# How bare bones can an ESP32 WROOM module still work

Tags: esp32

I'm creating a IOT device with the ESP32 WROOM module, I'm trying to make it as minimal as possible. I had some questions on how minimal can I go!

**Q1)** Is there a way to skip the EN pullup resistor? Just because it's one extra part that needs sourcing / added during manufacturing. Could I connect it directly to 3.3v, or would that just be a dead short? I've not tested this as didn't want to short out a module.

**Q2)** In researching this, I've noticed I should be using an RC delay circuit as well, I've built a few modules using ESP32 WROOM, just using a 10k resistor between 3.3v and EN pin with no issues. What's the point of this?

**Q3)** I've noticed everything works fine without the caps for the voltage regulator, it's a MCP1700 3.3v TO92 package. What are the risks of running without the caps? A test setup has been running a few days without issue, which I'm quite surprised about!

Programming isn't a problem as that will be done via another device I can push the module into, which will enable OTA updates via Bluetooth.

**Example very bare bones ESP32**:

[image: Example very bare bones ESP32]

Comment: Running without a cap is just a matter of how stable YOUR voltage can remain under YOUR variable power draw. Because you can does not necessarily mean others can, unfortunately; all depends on what the device is doing.  Most bare bones anything is nothing; it does nothing.

Comment: EN is not already internally pulled up? So, I understand that you can let it unconnected.  You can test it. If you need a reset button then you would connect there a push button to pull it low.

Comment: Regarding Q3, besides the other comments, without caps you could have problems with the supply current. That LDO can provide only 250mA, what could be not enough sometimes when the ESP32 in busy with the wifi or heavy tasks. The recommended supply is 500mA or more. It consumes a lot for short periods, for that the big caps can help. I have ran the esp32 with the MCP1700, but with relative big caps.

Comment: @Gos I don't think it's internally pulled up. My very first esp32 project failed, as I didn't have that pulled up and had to bodge a resistor in to get it to power up.  Unless you know something I don't, but leaving it floating didn't work for me, can give it another test I guess but don't think so.

Comment: You are right, is not pulled up.  Maybe it works as you suggest, directly connected to VDD, I don't know. The problem with all these topics is that it can work when you test, but it doesn't mean that it will work always or will not produce other problems later hard to track, or in slightly different conditions. e.g. the caps.

Comment: 1. yes, you can hard-wire to vcc if you don't need a reset button or don't mind dead-shorting the LDO to reset (haha). 2. if the power supply takes a while to stabilize on power-on, you can brownout the ESP and it won't boot, the delay helps ensure a steady input voltage before attempting to boot, which draws a bit of current right at the start, which is often a bad time to ask for current. 3. Like a lot of EE questions, "it depends". you can skip the LDO input cap for sure. If you skip the output cap, you pass more transients and noise, and sag voltage under bursts of power like wifi.